# Can't get flexbox to work in IE/Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari, flexbox, vendor-prefix

This all works perfectly in Chrome on my MBP, but breaks endlessly on the other browsers. I have used, https://autoprefixer.github.io/ to generate the necessary prefixes but to no avail.

Maybe someone can spot where I am going wrong? I striped the prefixed code out because I don't know what is affecting what now, so it's a bit of a blank slate... Heres the code and associated screenshots

[image]

[image]

Code is modified because of so many diff nested div's in here. Order will be parent > child etc..

```
.recommendation-modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 202;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 70vh;

.rec-right--container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4B77BE;
    color: #fff;

.rec-right--body {
      display: -moz-flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flex;
      display: flex;
      -moz-flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 20px;
      height: 100%;
      @media (max-width: $screen-sm) {
        flex-direction: row;
      }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML or a pen link?

Comment: More importantly what versions of these browsers are you testing in?

Comment: We need both HTML and CSS, as a working code snippet, to be able to provide a proper answer, though, combining Flexbox with `height: 100%` like that, is most likely the reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just needing to add the old syntax, I basically just found every old syntax possible and threw them in there until it worked...